# how do i save my current location using gps to parse database dynamically

Tags: java, android

am trying to save my current location latitude and longitude to parse database,, but am not be able to save it dynamically,, please anyone can help me to save it dynamically,,when ever i change my location i need to save my lactation,,,here is my code am saving my current location using static way..

```
public class Mapsh extends Activity {
    GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapsh);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        //map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);  
        ParseObject placeObject = new ParseObject("ParseStarterProjectActivity");
        ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(14.494300, 75.9197000);
        placeObject.put("location", point);

        try {
            placeObject.save();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have experience with android database applications????

Comment: save your gps locations in a database table and parse them dynamically when you start your activity... if you need any help email me I'll send a project done by me.. which contain the same thing dehanpramoda@gmail.com